# Gallery2 says ImageMagick Identify binary fails but logs no erros

Tags: imagemagick

Gallery2 claims ImageMagic Fails with no error:

[image: screen shot]

```
Binary Name     Pass/Fail
identify        Failed  

                Error messages:    
                Binary output:

                /nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/modules/imagemagick/data/test.gif GIF 50x50 50x50+0+0 8-bit sRGB 8c 232B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

And the logs look clear:

```
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
realpath(/nfs)
is_dir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
Loading plugin imagemagick
imagemagick plugin successfully instantiated
Check the version of the imagemagick plugin
The version of the imagemagick plugin is ok
getcwd()
chdir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/)
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
realpath(/nfs)
is_dir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/gm)
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/identify)
realpath(/nfs)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/identify)
getParameter exec.beNice for core plugin
Executing: ( "/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/identify" 
"/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/modules/imagemagick/data/test.gif"
)
2>"/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbgLBlarX"
getParameter exec.expectedStatus for core plugin
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbgLBlarX)
filesize(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbgLBlarX)
unlink(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbgLBlarX)
Regular Output:
/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/modules/imagemagick/data/test.gif
GIF 50x50 50x50+0+0 8-bit sRGB 8c 232B 0.000u 0:00.000
Error Output:
Status: 0 (expected 0)
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
realpath(/nfs)
is_dir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/gm)
tempnam(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/,
imgk_)
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/convert)
realpath(/nfs)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/convert)
Executing: ( "/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/convert"  "-size"  "200x200"
 "-geometry"  "200x200" 
"/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/modules/imagemagick/data/test.gif"
 "gif:/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/imgk_e8b0rW"
)
2>"/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbg9l8WsV"
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbg9l8WsV)
filesize(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbg9l8WsV)
unlink(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbg9l8WsV)
Regular Output:
Error Output:
Status: 0 (expected 0)
unlink(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/imgk_e8b0rW)
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
realpath(/nfs)
is_dir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/gm)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/combine)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/composite)
is_executable(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/composite)
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
realpath(/nfs)
is_dir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/gm)
tempnam(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/,
imgk_)
Executing: ( "/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/composite"  "-geometry" 
"+0+0" 
"/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/modules/imagemagick/data/test.jpg"
 "/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/modules/imagemagick/data/test.gif"
 "gif:/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/imgk_Z8ZHnV"
)
2>"/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbg8tRyiV"
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbg8tRyiV)
filesize(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbg8tRyiV)
unlink(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbg8tRyiV)
Regular Output:
Error Output:
Status: 0 (expected 0)
unlink(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/imgk_Z8ZHnV)
chdir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery)
```

So if there aren't any errors why does Gallery2 not agree with ImageMagick? Here's hoping someone has come across a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this problem migrating gallery2 to a new server. The old sever was running ImageMagick 6.7.x.y while the new server installed version 6.8.x.y

This comment on their forum clarifies what's happening and offers a working ImageMagickToolkitHelper.class:
http://galleryproject.org/node/110528#comment-401029

ImageMagick changed the output from identify, and the gallery2 tests fail when they don't receive the expected output.

I hope this helps!